# Finding Route Children For Breadcrumbs Angular 6

Tags: angular, breadcrumbs

Currently I am busy testing ways to contain breadcrumbs in my Angular App. I found a tutorial and followed it and so the code that follows is from the [this](https://brianflove.com/2016/10/23/angular2-breadcrumb-using-router/) tutorial.

The problem that I am facing at the moment is checking whether the currently activated route has children. This is what is currently being returned from the code checking whether the route has children:

[image]

As you can see it is returning an array with the children array inside this array. What I need to do is assign this inner array to the children variable.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I tried filtering but it did not seem to work either? I know it's probably a simple fix. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar. Not exactly sure what you are trying to do but to access the data in the first child you can do this:

```
const firstChild = this.route.snapshot.firstChild
console.log(firstChild.data)
```

See if that does the job.

To expand on this, my ngOnInit looks like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.updateTitle()
  this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this.updateTitle()
    }
  })
}

private updateTitle() {
  const firstChild = this.route.snapshot.firstChild
  console.log(firstChild.data)
  // more code
}
```

The updateTitle method is called in ngOnInit and inside subscribe. I think this is necessary to catch it on init and on route change. May not effect you, depends on your component organisation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it seems to only return an empty object?

Comment: i assume firstChild is ok but firstChild.data is empty object?

Comment: ok so if firstChild is set then the route has children ... you can assign data to the children in your route configuration (not sure thats what you want to do) - you can set any data as route data using the data property (static data) or the resolve property (dynamic data) using a resolver

Comment: example ... path: 'accounts',
  component: BasicLayoutComponent,
  data: {
    name: 'hello'
  }

Comment: Yes so that is what I am doing, I have something called `breadcrumbs` and this is the data that is supposed to be displayed, however I first need to try sort out this and then I will sort out that. So are you saying that if `firstChild` has a value then the route has children?

Comment: I believe that is correct, test it out to be 100% sure

Comment: I think it is a problem with my routing, will open this up again if I can fix it.